# How do I install version 2.4.3 of python-requests on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty?

Tags: ubuntu, python-requests, apt-get

I need to use version 2.4.3 of python-requests to download Coursera videos via course-dl.  However, I cannot upgrade to that version using apt-get in Ubuntu 14.04.01:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade python-requests
...
python-requests is already the newest version.
```

My current version of python-requests is 2.2.1-1 .  Is there another way besides working with the xx.tar.gz tarball?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using pip to install the latest version of python-requests, after removing the version installed by apt-get.  This post helps me understand how the two work together:  [What is the difference between installing a package using pip vs. apt-get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874527/what-is-the-difference-between-installing-a-package-using-pip-vs-apt-get) .